# C# надстрочные индексы

Tags: c#, строки, индексы, формат

Вопрос в следующем. Вам нужна строка, в которой формула, что нибудь вроде

T^(A+B+Abc)

оставлять в таком виде вы ее не хотите, хотите ы цивилизованном, понятном для чтения, как в том же ворде например. 
Так вот, перерыв все, что только можно и найдя лишь юникод символы для отдельных случаев, я спрашиваю вас - как образом можно отформатировать строку в C# в таком виде? есть какие-то управляющие последовательности или что-то еще?
в html есть теги  и , должно же быть что-то и в C#, если уж как то это делается в пакете MS Office

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам придётся хорошо поработать. Например, более-менее адекватный код для вашего случая на WPF такой:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespaceHere.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Typography" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="24">
            <Italic>T</Italic><!--
                --><Span Typography.Variants="Superscript"><!--
                    -->(<Italic>A</Italic>&#x200a;+&#x200a;<!--
                     --><Italic>B</Italic>&#x200a;+&#x200a;<!--
                     --><Italic>Abc</Italic>)</Span>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Он выдаёт вот что:

[image: рендеринг математики]

Подробности:

- Нужен шрифт Open Type, например, Palatino. В других шрифтах типографские эффекты не работают.
- Бинарные операции отбиты вручную тонкими шпациями (`&#x200a;`).
- В XAML'е пробелы внутри `TextBlock`'а значимые, пришлось их закомментировать. Если вы будете собирать контент вручную в code-behind, это не проблема.

---

Если вам нужен реально хороший рендеринг формул, советую посмотреть на TeX. В нём исходный текст

```
$T^{(A\mathop{+}B\mathop{+}Abc)}$
```

форматируется в такое:

[image: TeX output]